# Error [] invalid range

Tags: perl

I am getting a range error while matching regular expressions with terms like below:

```
(5r)-6-(4-{[2-(3-Iodobenzyl)-3-Oxocyclohex-1-En-1-Yl]Amino}Phenyl)-5-Methyl-4,5-Dihydropyridazin-3(2h)-One

show range error at 2-(
```

Can somebody tell me how to turn off the effect of such characters like brackets, range operator etc.?

Comment: You should try to explain your problem more thoroughly in your question, rather than having it extorted from you in comments to answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is not hard - just use `\Q` before and `\E` after such a term.

Say,
`/\Q(4-{[2-(3-Iodobenzyl)-3-Oxocyclohex\E/`.

You only cannot have `\E` in the given term.

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods of escaping/quoting those operators:

1. using [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

   ```
   my $var = quotemeta("(5r)-6-(4-{[2-(3-...")

   print "match\n" if($input =~ m/hello $var world/) ;
   ```
2. using `\Q...\E`

   Just enclose your string with `\Q...\E` also escapes any regex-operators. You can use this directly in the regex:

   ```
   if($input =~ m/hello \Q(5r)-6-(4-{[2-(3-Io...\E world/)
   ```

   Or with variable expansion:

   ```
   my $var = "(5r)-6-(4-{[2-(3-Io...";
   if($input =~ m/hello \Q$var\E world/)
   ```

Comment: I have a list of words that I have to match, it works  for rest but not for this with terms like above     if($z=~m/\b\$a[$i]$\b/i)... where $a[$i] which has the names as above, so the above term is the entire string that is to be matched\

Comment: One more question is if i use the above \Q..\E I am able to escape the dash characters. My question is what if i have to match doxorubicin perl is giving me a match even for epi-doxorubicin. Please tell me how to use both the \Q..\E and the exact term

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. So your texts (like the one in your questions) are in the array `@a`? And you want to match against the entire input string `$z`? Then try: `if($z =~ m/^\Q$a[$i]\E$/)`

Comment: I have every element in $z and it is to be matched with elements present in $a[$i] array, so strings like above are in $z while the array $a[$i] is the list that i have as a reference for comparison

Comment: And how are those elements separated? With whitespace? Could you edit your question and add a little sample of your input?

Comment: Here is the explanation, input from command line is stored in $z, I am using a foreach loop to process every element from the input. I have a reference to which i am comparing the input to. The reference is a column and has a single value/string on each line.